# Hyperledger Composer custom REST API server in Multiuser mode

Tags: rest, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, loopback

I have a problem with enabling multiusers after generating custom loopback app using this tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/customizing-the-rest-server
The problem is that there is no system/historian /system/identities /system/identities/bind endpoints.   That's why there is no possibility to import CARD for using multiuser mode.

Comment: did you answer Yes to connect to an existing, deployed business network on generation?

Comment: Yeah, sure. But in the generator, there is no question about the multiuser mode... Here is a similar issue on GitHub https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/4210 But we've already added that endpoints to my app and managed to implement custom API